# selecting and displaying ranked items and a user's votes, a la reddit, digg, et al

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance, voting

when selecting ranked objects from a database (eg, articles users have voted on), what is the best way to show:

- the current page of items
- the user's rating, per item (if they've voted)

rough schema:

```
articles: id, title, content, ...
user: id, username, ...
votes: id, user_id, article_id, vote_value
```

is it better/ideal to:

1. select the current page of items
2. select the user's vote, limiting them to the page of items with an 'IN' clause

or

1. select the current page of items and just 'JOIN' vote data from the table of user votes

or, something entirely different?

this is theoretically in a high-traffic environment, and using an rdbms like mysql. fwiw, i see this on the side of "thinking it out before doing" and not "premature optimization."

thanks!

Comment: A join (probably a LEFT JOIN) would likely be better, but it's hard to help unless you sketch the relevant columns of the relevant tables' schemas.

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN would be faster; it would save a round trip to the database.

However, I wouldn't worry at all about this until you actually get some traffic.  Many people have spoken out against [premature optimization](http://www.acm.org/ubiquity/views/v7i24_fallacy.html), I'll quote a random one:

> More computing sins are committed in
>   the name of efficiency (without
>   necessarily achieving it) than for any
>   other single reason - including blind
>   stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to order on votes, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  a.*, (
                SELECT  SUM(vote_value)
                FROM    votes v
                WHERE   v.article_id = a.id
                ) AS votes
        FROM    article a
        )
ORDER BY
        votes DESC
LIMIT 100, 110
```

This will count the votes and paginate in a single query.

If you want to show only the user's own votes, use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a.*, vote_value
FROM    articles a
LEFT JOIN
        votes v
ON      v.user_id = @current_user
        AND v.article_id = a.id
ORDER BY
        a.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100, 110
```

Having an index on `(vote_user, vote_item)` will greatly improve this query.

Note that you can make `(vote_user, vote_item)` a `PRIMARY KEY` for votes, which will improve this query even more.

Comment: The way I read the question, he'd like to display a page of news items, and then retrieve the votes of the current user for those items.